# Android ListView inside ScrollView Glide to load images off FireBase not loading always

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I have a ListView inside a ScrollView that will be displaying images and text. The text is displayed perfectly. The images however aren't. If I scroll the list slowly - all the images load perfectly without fail, but if I go really fast they never get loaded. I think it's how I set up where I am calling the method but this is my first day in Android. Below are the resources, layouts, and classes.

**How I added Text and an ImageView inside list:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

**The class to go along with it:**

```
public class someClass extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<String> web;
    ImageView imageView;
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
    final ArrayList<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<>();
    public galveon_character_creation_spelllist(Activity context,
                      ArrayList<String> web) {
        super(context, R.layout.someClass, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.someClass, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);


        imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web.get(position));
        getImages(position);

        return rowView;
    }

    public void getImages(Integer position) {
        storageRef.child("FolderRef/" + web.get(position) + ".png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                //imageView.setImageURI(null);
                //imageView.setImageURI(uri);
                Glide.with(getContext())
                        .load(uri) // the uri you got from Firebase
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.unknown) //this would be your default image (like default profile or logo etc). it would be loaded at initial time and it will replace with your loaded image once glide successfully load image using url.
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) //using to load into cache then second time it will load fast.
                        .animate(R.anim.fade_in) // when image (url) will be loaded by glide then this face in animation help to replace url image in the place of placeHolder (default) image.
                        .fitCenter()//this method help to fit image into center of your ImageView
                        .into(imageView); //Your imageView variable

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.unknown);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`web` are just text that line up with the picture names. Also when the activity loads the list, all the "cells" that are see do not load, but when you scroll down slowly and back up the images appear (if you scroll slowly).

If I need to post more information I can. Still learning how Android works.

Comment: why do you put ListView inside scrollview when listview manages scolling itself? Did you tried .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE);?

Comment: Use RecyclerView instead ListView for better result or use ViewHolder in your list adapter class if you want to use only ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try, giving imageview as a parameter to the getImage instead of global variable.
Eg:

```
    // inside getView
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    getImages(position, imageView);

    // GetImage
    public void getImages(Integer position, ImageView im) {
       ....
    }
```

Comment: @Torewin happy coding

Answer (score 1):

First thing, it is good to implement ViewHolder pattern in your listing or use RecyclerView. In your current situation, you are inflating the view over and over again which is not necessary and can degrade performance on your app if the view is too complex. You can read more about ViewHolder pattern [here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        //Inflate the view once if the view is null
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.someClass, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt)
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        //retrieve the reference of the inflated view
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtTitle.setText(web.get(position));
    getImages(holder.imageView, position);
    return convertView;
}

public void getImages(ImageView imageView, int position) {
    storageRef.child("FolderRef/" + web.get(position) + ".png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            //imageView.setImageURI(null);
            //imageView.setImageURI(uri);
            Glide.with(getContext())
                    .load(uri) // the uri you got from Firebase
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.unknown) //this would be your default image (like default profile or logo etc). it would be loaded at initial time and it will replace with your loaded image once glide successfully load image using url.
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) //using to load into cache then second time it will load fast.
                    .animate(R.anim.fade_in) // when image (url) will be loaded by glide then this face in animation help to replace url image in the place of placeHolder (default) image.
                    .fitCenter()//this method help to fit image into center of your ImageView
                    .into(imageView); //Your imageView variable

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.unknown);
        }
    });
}

static class ViewHolder {
   TextView txtTitle;
   ImageView imageView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this information.I will use this method when I go back and rewrite and structure everything - right now I am just getting a working model.